# MySql select inside another select?

Tags: mysql, select

Is there any way to do this?

```
SELECT sum(price) from table2 WHERE id=(SELECT theid FROM table1 WHERE user_id="myid")
```

I have table1 with items' IDs, that a user has purchased. I want to calculate the sum of all items purchased by user.

Is the query above legal? If not, what's the correct form?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Change `where id=(SELECT` to `where id IN (SELECT`

Or what you really want is probably:

```
SELECT sum(price) FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.id = table1.theid WHERE table1.user_id = 'my_id'
```

Answer (score 7):

you query is ok, as long as the [subselect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html) is returning only one row every time.

if there are more rows returned, you'll have to change your query to:

```
[...] WHERE id IN (SELECT [...]
```

**NOTE:** in you case, a simple inner join like others suggested would be much more redable (and maybe a tiny little bit faster) - but what you've written is absolutely ok (there are always multiple ways to get the desired result - and it's now always easy to tell wich one is "the best" ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the JOIN syntax

```
SELECT sum(price) from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.theID = t2.id
WHERE t1.user_id="myid"
```

Should give you the same result

Answer (score 1):

A `JOIN` would be more readable:

```
SELECT SUM(price) FROM table2
INNER JOIN table1 ON table2.id = table1.theid
WHERE table1.user_id = "myid"
```

Comment: and would allow vast optimisations

Answer (score 1):

You should use SQL `JOIN` to provide that functionality.

```
SELECT SUM(table2.price) JOIN table1 ON
table2.id=table1.theid WHERE table1.user_id="myid"
```